# How to generate a csproj with Frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk, frameworks

I need to generate a WebApi project in .NetCore 3.1 that can compile without internet access.
So all NuGet packages, and such, must be included as .dll's.
I've already added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll` as a file reference.
I've added a package reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`.
I've changed the project type to SDK style and the Web variant:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

But WebApi projects that I use VS to generate hav Frameworks `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App` that are not in the CSProj.
How do I add these when generating a project from scratch?

Edit:
I've added FrameworkReference for both these:
      `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`
However, now all my Frameworks, Packages and Project references in the UI present warnings. Trying to start a Build produces a "The operation could not be completed" popup.

Edit 2:
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web Project types are [supposed](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-new-project-file-program-and-the-generic-host-in-asp-net-core-3/#the-new-project-file-and-changes-to-the-shared-framework) to have the FrameworkReference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App by default. However when I create my project manually with this type the frameworks are not available. Including if I manually add the framework references in the csproj.

Comment: Try to install .NET Core SDK first

Comment: Or try `Update-Package -reinstall`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I do have the SDK installed, projects created with VS work fine. The issue is with project generated by custom code. So by writing text to a file.

Comment: @MrFox please, show us how do you generate it

Comment: @Fabio It doesn't recognize these frameworks as installed packages. Update-Framework doesn't exist.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The project file is created by writing it's content to a `StringBuilder`. The text is converted to a byte array and written to disk `File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, dataBytes)`. I've made manual changes as well to test whether they would solve the problem.  There are postbuild commands as well, but they can't rely on anything from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to change the TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```